# ApacheのAllowEncodedSlashesの設定内容を確認したい

Tags: apache, freebsd

Apacheの設定内容を確認したいのですが、どのような方法があるでしょうか。
今特に知りたいのではAllowEncodedSlashesがどうなっているかです。(onなのかoffなのか)

共用のレンタルサーバなのですがhttpd.confの入っているらしき場所は権限が無く確認できませんでした。
OSはFreeBSD バージョン9です。

Comment: シェルは使えるのですか？

Comment: はい。一応極基本的なコマンドは使えます。(レンタルサーバで使えるかという意味でも、私自身が扱えるかという意味でも)

Answer (score 1):

ドキュメントを見る限り、デフォルトの値は "Off" のようです。

[AllowEncodedSlashes ディレクティブ](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes)

また、設定ファイルの場所や中身を確認するには、以下のコマンドを実行する方法があるようです。
(Linux での例なので、FreeBSD でもそのまま使えるかは試していません)
なお、設定ファイルの中身を確認する際には、適切なアクセス権限が必要になると思います。

[Apache の情報をコマンドラインで取得する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/bezeklik/items/7bbfcbcfeb05c1d57fec)

> #### 設定ファイルの一覧の取得
>
> ```
> httpd -t -D DUMP_CONFIG 2>/dev/null | grep '# In' | awk '{print $4}'
> ```
>
> #### 設定ファイルの内容の取得
>
> ```
> httpd -t -D DUMP_CONFIG 2>/dev/null | grep -v '#'
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございます。このサイトで紹介している二つはメッセージが出てだめでした。(Ambiguous output redirect.)

Comment: シェルは何でしょう？
まあ、要は内容が見られればいいので、

`httpd -t -D DUMP_CONFIG 2>& | grep -v '#'`

か

`httpd -t -D DUMP_CONFIG |& grep -v '#'`

か、どっちかで行けるかと。

Comment: @anlovean 紹介した記事は Linux = bash シェルを使った例なので、FreeBSD だとお使いのログインシェルの種類によってリダイレクトの記号が変わると思います。まずは `httpd -t -D DUMP_CONFIG` まででコマンドが実行できているかを確認してみるとよいと思います。

Comment: シェルは /bin/csh でした(echo $SHELLで確認)。
新たに教えて頂いた最初のhttpd -t -D DUMP_CONFIG 2>& | grep -v '#'は、Ambiguous output redirect.と表示されます。
次にhttpd -t -D DUMP_CONFIG |& grep -v '#' のほうはCommand not found.と出ます。
そこで確認したところhttpdはそもそもhttpdと打っただけでCommand not found.と表示されます。
そこでhttpdコマンドの場所を探しましたが、せいぜい/var/run/httpdが引っかかるだけで後は Permission denied と表示されるばかりで見つかりませんでした。
apachectl(apache2ctlも)コマンドについても同様です。/usr/local/apache もPermission deniedとなります。
/usr/binの中にもhttpdはありませんでした。
これはやっぱりレンタルサーバーということで一般ユーザーはhttpdコマンドが使えないということなんでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね、実行が許されていないっぽいですね…

Comment: やはりそうですか。残念だけど勉強になりました。助言くださったみなさんありがとうございます！